# Create a flag to know if a column is in multiple intervals

Tags: sql

I am struggling in SQL to create a flag based on an interval.

This is my use case:

Table: result

| merchandising_month | client_id | start_month_12m_before | end_month_12m_before | start_month | end_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202106 | client1 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 |
| 202006 | client1 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 |
| 202003 | client2 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 |
| 202012 | client3 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 |
| 202012 | client4 | 201910 | 202009 | 202003 | 202109 |
| 202012 | client4 | 201910 | 202009 | 202001 | 202109 |

The objective is based on the client_id, I need to flag his activity.

If merchandising_month is between start_month and end_month for a record and merchandising_month is between start_month_12m_before and end_month_12m_before, we flag it to yes, otherwise to no

| merchandising_month | client_id | start_month_12m_before | end_month_12m_before | start_month | end_month | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202106 | client1 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 | yes |
| 202006 | client1 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 | yes |
| 202003 | client2 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 | no |
| 202012 | client3 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 | no |
| 202002 | client4 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 | yes |
| 202104 | client4 | 201910 | 202009 | 202010 | 202109 | yes |

I have tried to do a CASE WHEN filter but I find null values, I tried also an inner join, but without any success.

There is what I have tried:

```sql
select * ,
(
    CASE
    WHEN
    (
        (r1.merchandising_month >= r1.start_month_12m_before)
        AND (r1.merchandising_month <= r1.end_month_12m_before) 
    )
    THEN 'No'
    WHEN 
    (
        (r1.merchandising_month BETWEEN r1.start_month_12m_before AND r1.end_month_12m_before)
        AND (r2.merchandising_month BETWEEN r1.start_month AND r1.end_month)
    )
    THEN 'Yes'
    END
) AS activity_N
FROM result r1 INNER JOIN result r2 ON r1.client_id = r2.client_id
```

And it gives me the null values for each line not answering to Yes condition

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: These are either numeric values or char values. Either way can't you just use?: `case when merch_date between start_month and end_month and merch_date between start_month2 and end_month2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end`

Comment: Your attempting to use an inner join and the facts that some clients have two rows makes me think you've left out part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the thing is that the merch date comes from 2 different rows, that's why I am trying to that way

Comment: In your sample data that date is the same in both rows. I think you need to clarify the actual question. As is your inner join isn't going to work though.

Comment: I think that inner join is not the good approach indeed. What I want to say is that, if I apply this filter, it will take only into consideration the concerned raw, not the other one for the same client

Comment: How is 202106 between 201910 and 202009?

Comment: You haven't described how to tell them apart. I kind suspect you don't need an inner join but I'm not sure about much here at this point.

Comment: Sorry, I raw is one record in the table, so for example for client 1, we can see that merchandising_month is between start_month and end_month for the first raw and between start_month_12m_before and end_month_12m_before for the second raw

Comment: @stickybit 202106 is not between 201910 and 202009 but between 202010 and 202109, and this is the first part of the condition, since the different merchandising_month for this client must be in the 2 intervals

Comment: You wrote "If merchandising_month is between start_month and end_month for a record **and merchandising_month is between start_month_12m_before and end_month_12m_before, we flag it to yes, otherwise to no**" (emphais: me). In the first row of your expected result `activity` is "yes" but the `merchandising_month` 202106 is not between `start_month_12m_before` and `end_month_12m_before` which are 201910 and 202009 as you see for yourself. So `activity` cannot be "yes" for that row but must be "no". Something is wrong in your description.

Comment: Indeed, but since we are looking to confirm that both conditions are true over at least one of the rows for the same client, we could have a merchandising_month which is not between the interval for one record but it is for another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to confirm that both conditions hold true over at least one of the rows for the same client:

```
select *,
    case when
        max(case when merchandising_month between start_month and end_month then 1 end)
            over (partition by client_id) = 1 and 
        max(case when merchandising_month between start_month_12m_before and end_month_12m_before then 1 end)
            over (partition by client_id) = 1
        then 'yes' else 'no' end as activity
from T
```

This would not differentiate the rows in any fashion. The conditions could both be true for the same row simultaneously or multiple times across the set.

The way this works is to look around at each row with the same `client_id`. For each of those the conditions are tested using a `case` expression that evaluates to 1 when the condition passes. The `max()` will collapse multiple values into a single result so that a maximum value across all rows being equal to 1 will indicate that at least one row has passed the test. The value 1 could be changed to something like `'Passed'` or `'True'` if preferred.

Comment: I didn't know this functions. Could you please explain or share a link that explains the usage of max and over (partition by client_id) = 1 please ? or I will google it if it takes time to do it. Thanks for your answer